# JSP JasperException while using dates

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to submit a number as an input and I'm getting this error. I don't know what's going wrong! Please give your insights

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /SubmitMovie.jsp at line 14

11: int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rowId").trim());
12: int membid=0;
13: String[] values=request.getParameterValues("memb");
14: int len=values.length;
15: for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
16: {
17:     if(!values[i].equalsIgnoreCase(""))


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.SubmitMovie_jsp._jspService(SubmitMovie_jsp.java:67)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Which is line 67 as mentioned in the stacktrace `org.apache.jsp.SubmitMovie_jsp._jspService(SubmitMovie_jsp.java:67)`

Answer (score 0):

From stack trace given you are getting `NullPointerException`

```
11: int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rowId").trim());
12: int membid=0;
13: String[] values=request.getParameterValues("memb");
14: int len=values.length;
15: for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
16: {
17:     if(!values[i].equalsIgnoreCase(""))
```

Check few things

1. String array `values` is not nullas you are trying to access `values.length`
2. `rowId` is always not null, non-empty and present in the parameter as you are parsing it to convert into `Integer`